# Firebase Function is returning the wrong time

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

firebase cloud functions UTC time is off by four hours.

Im working on a react-native app for debating. I am working on getting each case to close by comparing the completion time to the time now. I am using a firebase cloud function to do this. The function was working perfectly last week however when i started working on the app this week the function was consolelogging the wrong time and when i do the same calculation from my app running on my computer it is correct so i can rule out how im calculating it!

```
const date = require('date-and-time');

const now           = new Date()
const currentDate   = date.format(now, 'MM/DD/YYYY, HH:mm:ss')                      
const dateFrom      = userCase.completionTime
const DateDiff      = require('date-diff')          
const date1         = new Date(dateFrom)
const date2         = new Date(currentDate) 
const difff         = new DateDiff(date1, date2)
const time          = difff.seconds()
const totalyesVotes =  _.size(yesVotes)
const totalnoVotes  =  _.size(noVotes)  

                              console.log(currentDate + "current time")
```

so i console.logged these at the same time this one from google cloud
05/06/2019, 20:50:49

and this one from my computer
05/06/2019, 16:50:49

Comment: If you think there is a bug in Cloud Functions, you should [file a bug report](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support?page=bug_or_feature) for that.  But I can assure you that the times on Cloud Functions are not off by four hours.  That would be critically bad.  What you are seeing is likely just a difference in timezone between your machine and Cloud Functions.

Comment: Is your timezone EDT by any chance? UTC time is 4 hours ahead (or more accurately EDT is UTC-04:00).  Are you sure your local output _is_ UTC?